# Do I have to configure daemon tools for Nginx or does Nginx handle its shutdown in a smarter way?

Tags: nginx, daemontools

I use daemon tools with gearman
I was thinking whether I should configure daemon tools for Nginx
or does it handle its shutdown (in case of memory issue, etc..) automatically?

Comment: Which OS/distribution?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: `service nginx start/stop` doesn't work for you?

Comment: it does.. Nginx works fine.. I was just asking if I need to use daemontools to "monitor" Nginx.. is it necessary?

Comment: If you're asking if you _can_ use `supervise` with `nginx`, the answer is yes.

Comment: You could, but there's little point. nginx supervises itself.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you! You answered my question precisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone who fell in love with daemontools thirteen years ago, I too try to supervise all the things.  nginx is a bit feisty though, you have to use at least `daemon off;` in your config to run it in the foreground, and `master_process off;` if you really don't want it spawning any children.  Just `exec` it then from your run program and it will behave like you expect.

I was cutting against the grain, however.  I've come to accept that nginx has supervision built in.  You'll notice that when you run it you get something like this:

```
$ psg nginx
root      1361     1  0 Mar31 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  1362  1361  0 Mar31 ?        00:18:10 nginx: worker process
www-data  1363  1361  0 Mar31 ?        00:18:44 nginx: worker process
$ pstree -p 1361
nginx(1361)─┬─nginx(1362)
            └─nginx(1363)
```

The master process is essentially `supervise`.  It's super lightweight and is solely responsible for making sure workers are running properly.  I've never *once* had it crash on me, even in some fairly busy environments.  So now I just let `init` stop/start it and worry about services I do need to supervise.

There are other considerations.  Check out what the official documentation has to say about it: http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/daemon_master_process_off.html

Comment: Doc TL;DR - `master_process off;` / `daemon off;` break zero-downtime upgrades and are mostly for Nginx developers.